# 2nd Order Differential Equation (Homogenous & Variable Coefficients)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, homogeneous-equation

I have the following differential equation:

$y''(x) + \frac{1}{x}y'(x)+\frac{\lambda x}{D}y(x) = 0$

From what I understand, DE's of this kind have a general solution of:

$y(x)=Ay_1(x)+By_2(x)$

but at least $y_1$ or $y_2$ must be known to solve completely (I don't know either) - but that sometimes it is possible to make an initial guess for $y_1$ or $y_2$.

Are there any other options for solving this? Perhaps Laplace transforms?

EDIT:

Boundary conditions are

$y(0)=A$

$y(X)=B$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$y''(x) + \frac{1}{x}y'(x)+Cxy(x) = 0 \qquad C=\frac{\lambda}{D}$$
Obviously this is an ODE of the Bessel kind (generalized). A convenient change of variable $X=\beta x^\gamma$ reduces it to the standard Bessel form.

Lasy people can use ready made formula : Eqs.$(6-7)$ in https://mathworld.wolfram.com/BesselDifferentialEquation.html giving $\alpha=0$ , $\beta=\frac23\sqrt{C}$ , $\gamma=\frac32$ , $n=0$ with the symbols in this paper.
$$y(x)=c_1 J_0\left(\frac23\sqrt{C}x^{3/2} \right)+c_2 Y_0\left(\frac23\sqrt{C}x^{3/2} \right)$$
$J_0$ and $Y_0$ are the Bessel functions of first and second kind.

UPDATE after the addition of conditions in the question :

Condition $y(0)=A$

Since $Y_0(0)$ is infinite this implies $c_2=0 \quad\implies\quad y(x)=c_1 J_0\left(\frac23\sqrt{C}x^{3/2} \right)$

And $J_0(0)=1\quad\implies\quad c_1=A$
$$y(x)=A\;J_0\left(\frac23\sqrt{C}x^{3/2} \right)$$

With condition $y(X)=B$ :
$$\begin{cases}
\text{if } B\neq A\;J_0\left(\frac23\sqrt{C}X^{3/2} \right) \text{ there is no solution.}\\
\text{if } B= A\;J_0\left(\frac23\sqrt{C}X^{3/2} \right)\text{ the solution is }y(x)=A\;J_0\left(\frac23\sqrt{C}x^{3/2} \right)
\end{cases}$$
Thus in the general case (any $A$ and $B$ except the particular value of $B$ defined above) there is no solution which satisfies both the ODE and the two conditions.

Comment: And when $C<0$ you write these in terms of Bessel functions $I_0$ and $K_0$.

Comment: Solving for $\lambda$ is my separation of variables constant. Can it be solved for using my boundary conditions if there is no "inverse" of Bessel functions?

Comment: There is no boundary condition specified in your question.

Comment: @JJacquelin Posted in edit

Comment: @Sterling Butters. The answer is updated according to the specified conditions.

Comment: @JJacquelin I'm sorry, so you are saying that a solution does exist so long as $B=AJ_0\left(\frac{2}{3}\sqrt{C}X^\frac{3}{2}\right)$ ? If so, how can one solve for $C$?

Comment: This was not asked in your question. The inverse functions of the Bessel functions are not standardized yet. For example see : https://www.reddit.com/r/math/comments/2q06hm/what_are_the_inverse_of_the_bessel_functions/ . So one cannot write an explicit formula with standard symbols. This doesn't mean that the inverse function doesn't exist. One have to use numerical calculus to compute them. (Often by iterative methods).